# jQuery/Grails- Detect Row in a Table when textbox is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

I need to recalculate a field A after changing a field B.

But they are in a row i a table with "n" number of rows (foreach).

To make the necessary recalculations I have to get the row that the change is made. Here is a example code. Thanks!

```js
 $('#number').keyup(function () {
        
               var num=parseFloat($('#number').val());
               var price=parseFloat($('#price').val());
              
               var newAmount= num*price;
               
               document.getElementById("priceAmount").value = newAmount;
               
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th> Name <th>
    <th> Product <th>
    <th> Price <th>
    <th> Number <th>
    <th> Price Amount <th>
  <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <g:each var="sale" status="i" in="${saleInstanceList}">
       <td>${sale.name}"></td>
       <td>${sale.product}"></td>
       <td>${sale.price}"></td>
       <g:hiddenField name="price" value="${sale.price}"/>
       <td><g:textField name="number" value="${sale.number}"></g:textField></td>
       <td><g:textField name="priceAmount" value="${sale.priceAmount}"></g:textField></td>
     </tr>
     </g:each>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to make a jquery function per row and create variables with row-id etc ...